# Call a custom module helper from template file of another module

Tags: php, magento, module

I have created an new module. The module is connected with another database. Now I want to call the helper class from another module template file let say "description.pthml". I used the following code.

```
$_helper = $this->helper('ForumProdPosts/output');
```

But I am getting  error "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_ForumProdPosts_Helper_Output' not found in /home/black/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546".

The helper class is located in local/MyWebsite/ForumProdPosts/Helper/Output.php having the following code.

```
class MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts_Helper_Output extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('forumprodposts_helper_output_construct', array('helper'=>$this));
    }

    public function getForumPosts(){
        echo "I m here";
            exit;
    }
}
```

Also the config.xml of my module is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <forumprodposts>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts</module>
                    <frontName>forumprodposts</frontName>
                </args>
            </forumprodposts>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <forumprodposts>
                    <file>forumprodposts.xml</file>
                </forumprodposts>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <forumprodposts>
                <class>MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts_Helper</class>
            </forumprodposts>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <forumprodposts_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>phpbb_database</use>
                </connection>
            </forumprodposts_write>
            <forumprodposts_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>phpbb_database</use>
                </connection>
            </forumprodposts_read>
            <forumprodposts_setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </forumprodposts_setup>
            <forumprodposts_database>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[user]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[forumdb]]></dbname>
                    <model>mysql4</model>
                    <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </forumprodposts_database>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Seems to me the magento not recognizing my module. Help me what I am doing wrong.

I have just realized that my module is not appearing in the configuration/advanced section of admin panel. I have done reindexing and clear cashe also the MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts.xml in etc/modules have the follwing code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the naming convention must match the name defined in the config.xml.
So try the code given below

```
$_helper = $this->helper('forumprodposts/output');
// all in small letter as defined in your xml file
```

Comment: still not working. Is there any problem in module XML, because the module also not appears configuration/advanced in admin panel

Comment: Did you activated your module from app/etc/modules/MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts.xml and remove cache and done reindexing.

Comment: Try one thing more..Instead of using  MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts in your module name, you can use Mywebsite_Forumprodposts, and activate it, then check whether it is active? <Mywebsite_Forumprodposts>
       <version>0.1.0</version>
</Mywebsite_Forumprodposts>  ..Do the same changes in app/etc/Mywebsite_Forumprodposts.xml

Comment: Its appears now and active. but the helper error is still there

Comment: I have changed all instances of ForumProdPosts to Forumprodposts in config.xml also in Mywebsite_Forumprodposts.xml but still the same error.

Comment: Ok..Now. You need to change the class name from MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts_Helper_Output extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
to Mywebsite_Forumprodposts_Helper_Output extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract..then refresh your cache, and rebuild your index..Hope It will work

Comment: still that error appears Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Forumprodposts_Helper_Output' not found :(

Answer (score 1):

`Mage::helper()` method works with the xml nodes in the config.xml, not with the name of your module.

When Magento starts, all the config.xml are concatenated in one big xml file. In this file, the node global/helpers includes all the helpers defined in all your modules. The helper method use those nodes to load the right class :

```
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

So here, to access to `MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts_Helper_Output`, you've to write :

```
$_helper = $this->helper('forumprodposts/output');
```

Comment: Have you created the file etc/modules/MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts.xml, like this ?
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
         <modules>
            <MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool> <!-- if your module is in app/code/local -->
            </MyWebsite_ForumProdPosts>
         </modules>
    </config>

If yes, try to simplify your xml, and make a test file to check if the module appears in your Magento config, with Mage::getConfig();